# Can't bind to 'qrc-value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-qrcode' in Ionic 4.2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, qr-code

**when using the NgxQRCodeModule from 'ngx-qrcode2' in Ionic 4.2.0 I always get this error:**

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'qrc-value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-qrcode'.
1. If 'ngx-qrcode' is an Angular component and it has 'qrc-value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-qrcode' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

```
 <ion-card *ngIf="createdCode"></ion-card>
    <ngx-qrcode  [ERROR ->][(qrc-value)] = "createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
    <ion-card-content >
    <p> Value: {{createdCode}}</p"):
```

**Things I have tried:**
I have imported the NgxQRCodeModule to page.module.ts and app.module.ts. I have also tried

```
[(qrc-value)] = "createdCode"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says `qrc-value` is not a property of `ngx-qrcode`. To set the value of the QR code just use the `[value]` property like this:

```
 <ngx-qrcode [value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
```

For further improvements you can check the example in its git [page](https://github.com/techiediaries/ngx-qrcode#how-to-use-ngx-qrcode2)